# MVC 4 Persist Data throughout website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to find the best way to persist the logged in user's data throughout the app and for the session.  I'm fairly new to MVC but with web forms, it was as simple as declaring a public property on the master page and setting the CurrentUser object once logged in.  I've tried that with my MVC app but I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance object" error.  I should not that I have a Base class and a CustomController class that all my controllers derive from

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public CompanyUser CurrentUser
    {
        get { return (Session["CurrentCompanyUser"] as CompanyUser); }
        set { Session["CurrentCompanyUser"] = value; }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I store the CurrentUser object in the Session object, like so (this is in the Login Action):

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (WebSecurity.Login(model.Username, model.Password))
    {
        using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
        {
            int userId = WebSecurity.GetUserId(model.Username);
            User user = db.Users.Find(userId);

            if (user != null)
            {
                CompanyUser companyUser = db.CompanyUsers.Find(userId);

                if (companyUser.IsActive)
                {
                    CurrentUser = companyUser;

                    if (Roles.GetRolesForUser(model.Username).Contains("Administrator"))
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                    else
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine but when I try to access it from the DashboardController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    return View(new ImageModel() { ImageName = CurrentUser.Company.Logo });
}
```

I get the following error:
`The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

I'd like to be able to store the logged in User data (in the form of a `CompanyUser` object) and access it easily from any of my controllers.  Is this possible or is it more suitable to lookup this data with each page change?

Comment: it is because every tap some controller action calls, base controller is also instantiated and property is reinitialized

Comment: mvc is very different from web froms you cannot do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the code in using block:

```
using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
```

And the object which you are storing in the session which is a part of db.`db.CompanyUsers.Find(userId);` Which is incorrect. because `using()` disposes db object after it's use. and with this your customer object also get disposed.

Remove the using block and try.
As for dispose, you can dispose the object manually.

Comment: Removing it from the using statement allows it to work perfectly.  Thanks!