# retrive session varriable and use it to viewstart in MVC 4 (razor)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

hi I was trying to retrieve my session value and use it to _layout.cshtml, but every time i am getting null exception`(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)`  here is my code. what am i doing wrong. layout.cshtml could not load ~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml  layout. beacouse it isn't getting any  session value.

```
@{
    if(HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUserType"].ToString() == "superadmin" &&  HttpContext.Current.Session["DEPTNM"].ToString() == "AlchemyAdmin")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";

    }    
}
```

here is my controller code, i coudnt use my session value.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (DataAccess.LoginDAL.AdminIsValid(model.LOGINID, model.LOGINPW))
                {

                    var result = (from n in db.AslUsercoDbSet
                        where n.LOGINID == model.LOGINID &&
                              n.LOGINPW == model.LOGINPW
                        select new
                        {
                           companyid= n.COMPID, 
                           userid =  n.USERID, 
                           deptname= n.DEPTNM, 
                           usertype = n.OPTP
                        }
                        );
                    foreach (var n in result)
                    {
                        Session["loggedCompID"] = n.companyid;
                        Session["loggedUserID"] = n.userid;
                        Session["LoggedDepartment"] = n.deptname;
                        Session["LoggedUserType"] = n.usertype;
                    }

                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.LOGINID, true);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username or Password");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I am adding my dataaccess layer code here . this validate the user if exist.

```
 internal static bool AdminIsValid(string username, string password)
        {
            bool authenticated = false;

            string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM [AslUsercoes] WHERE LOGINID = '{0}' AND LOGINPW = '{1}'", username, password);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(ds);
 SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            authenticated = sdr.HasRows;
            conn.Close();
            return (authenticated);
        }
```

Comment: Seems nothing wrong with that code. Can you show us your controller code?

Comment: __Check for nullablity__. like `if(HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUserType"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["DEPTNM"] != null && HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUserType"].ToString() == "superadmin" &&  HttpContext.Current.Session["DEPTNM"].ToString() == "AlchemyAdmin")`

Comment: i have attached my controller code. please check if u can help me what am i doing wrong

Comment: is it throwing any exception !!!

Comment: try to do some thing like this,@using KCRM.Model.Models
@{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetail"] == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    UserSessionModel user = (UserSessionModel) HttpContext.Current.Session["UserDetail"];
    MenuSessionModel menu = (MenuSessionModel)HttpContext.Current.Session["PermissionDetail"];
}

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the how you are assigning the value to your session.

Session["LoggedUserType"]  = value (block must not have using() statement. because it will dispose your value object in this case.)

Please refer below link for this.

[MVC 4 Persist Data throughout website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962178/mvc-4-persist-data-throughout-website/25962333)

And Second,

You need to user full line (Html.ViewContext.HttpContext)

```html
@{
    if(Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Current.Session["LoggedUserType"].ToString() == "superadmin" &&  Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Current.Session["DEPTNM"].ToString() == "AlchemyAdmin")
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutHome.cshtml";

    }    
}
```